# create multiple tags with same name

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

We are able to create multiple tags which have the same name. It occurs only when we create a tag that contains 2 words.

Just create the same tag (which should contain 2 words) multiple times by increasing the space between the 2 words.
in the database, we can see the second images that are the same value that we type in the input box but in the name column, we can see that all the tags are similar. how to resolve this issue.

```
$('#tagTable_filter input').attr('id', 'tagSearch');
    $('#tagSearch').attr('maxlength','85');
    $("div.toolbar").html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-peacock hide" id="newTagBtn" ng-click="createNewTag()"><i class="fa fa-tag fa-tagging fa-fw"  > </i> New Tag</button>');
    $('.dataTables_filter input')
    .off()
    .on('keyup', function() {
        var searchTerm = this.value.toLowerCase();
        $("#msgBlock").addClass('hide');
        $("#deleteMsg").addClass('hide');
        $('#tagTable').DataTable().rows().search(searchTerm, true, false).draw();
        checkDataCount();
    });
    $("#tagTable_filter").append("<br><div class='validation-msg text-left' style='padding-top:10px;'><i class='fa fa-times-circle red'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>Only alphanumeric character and underscore is allowed in tagname.</span></div>");
    $(".validation-msg").hide();
    applyTagsMsgCalc();
};

$(document).on('click', '#tagTable .sorting', function() {
    var correctedSrchVal = $('#tagTable_filter input[type=search]').val().replace('\\b' , '');
    $('#tagTable_filter input[type=search]').val(correctedSrchVal);
});
```

Comment: you need to include the relevant code (html,css,js) to the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: The issue is that `"a b"` is not the same as `"a  b"` but HTML collapses whitespace to a single character - so they're not the same, but look the same.   Easiest solution is to do the same on your inputs before checking for duplicates, eg `tag = tag.replaceAll("  ", " ").trim()`.

Comment: The code provided seems to bear no resemblance to your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.